# using webpack's require.context is unable to return file content

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-5

I'm looking into loading a bunch of text files that are in a directory, and using their content in my code.
I tried using `fs` to read the files like this : `fs.readdir`but it doesn't work because my app is browser only, without server.

I found that you can use `webpack`'s `require.context()` to load the files so I used it like this :

```
const files = require.context('./my-directory', true, /\.txt$/);
files.keys().forEach((key) => {
  const fileContent = files(key);
  // do something with the file content
});
```

but `const fileContent = files(key);` is returning the file name and not the file content.

the docs don't seem to have much answers on how to deal with this and I'm stuck. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I was using the loader (`raw-loader`) incorrectly, and not making the correct call to get the file content. I was doing this in `webpack.config`:

```
    {
        test: /\.txt$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        loader: 'raw-loader',
    },
```

and the correct way was to remove the `type`
and the correct way to get the file content is like this :

```
const files = require.context('./my-directory', true, /\.txt$/);
files.keys().forEach((key) => {
  const file = files(key);
  const fileContent = file.default;
  // do something with the file content
});
```

hope this helps someone.